# How to return an instantiated data by flask ,that java can accept

Tags: java, python, flask

I defined an instantiation data by python like this:

```
class data:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.A = a
        self.B = b
```

if I just return d, there is an error when I run code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def response():
    d = data(1,2)
    return d
```

or

```
return jsonify(d)
```

or

```
return json.dump(d)
```

It seems that I am not serialize instantiation data into json formate properly.

How should I return data that Java can accept and call data like d.A?

Answer (score 0):

Smth. like this one:

```
class Data {
    private final int a;
    private final int b;

    public Data(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }   
}

public Data response() {
    return new Data(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: I am very grateful for your answer, but it seems that your code is running on java. I want to use python as the server and java as the client.

Answer (score -1):

Nowadays, JSON is the choice for data sharing among applications and programming languages!
Through the example of this code snippet you can see how we might send json data in response through a flask route!
For any further queries, please mention in the comments.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

#definition for class
class data:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.A = a
        self.B = b

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/')
def index():
    d = data(1,2)
    #'resp' is a dict which will contain the data we have to send
    resp = {'A':self.A, 'B':self.B}
    return jsonify(resp) #jsonify() converts data to json format.
```

Comment: Turning the object into a dict is unneccessary, and in the general case - with a nontrivial datastructure - very errorprone.